# What should I do to this rock between apple tree branches?

Tags: fruit-trees, apples, rocks

There is a rock stuck inside apple tree and I cannot get it off. I have bought this garden and previous owner has put it there. I cannot get it off unless I cut some branches of tree. Should I cut it or should I leave it there.
[image: Rock inside tree]
[image: Rock inside apple tree]
[image]

Comment: Look how clean the garden is. I guess the stone was put there for a reason. Leaving the stone there won't hurt the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a 2lb sledge hammer, striking the bottom tip of the rock?  Depends on how much the tree has grown around the rock.  People do some weird stuff.

Comment: I took out rocks but I injured tree a little bit. Maybe previous owber was trying to split branches.

Answer (score 0):

I think a crowbar would get that out without doing anything detrimental to the tree.